# Trouble understanding how to access nested list in list

Tags: c#, linq, system.reflection, jagged-arrays

I processing a soap response which the xml has a purchase order within items 
eg

```
<PurchaseOrder>
<WHID>2</WHID>
<Supplier_ID>00</Supplier_ID>
<POID>6</POID>
<CreateDate>2013-01-02T10:48:27.37+11:00</CreateDate>
<CurrencyName>Australian Dollars</CurrencyName>
<ShippingStatus>Departed</ShippingStatus>
<payment_terms></payment_terms>
<shipping_terms></shipping_terms>
<POStatus>Back-Order</POStatus>
<PurchaseOrderItems>
<PurchaseOrderItem>
<SKU>Shoe30</SKU>
<Product_ID>124064</Product_ID>
<QtyOrdered>9</QtyOrdered>
<QtyOutstanding>6</QtyOutstanding>
<BuyPriceEx>20.0000</BuyPriceEx>
<DirectCosts>0.0000</DirectCosts>
<SupplierBuyPrice>20.0000</SupplierBuyPrice>
</PurchaseOrderItem>
</PurchaseOrderItems>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

I have no issues putting this into a jagged list . my classes look like this

```
    public class PurchaseOrder
    {
        public string WHID { get; set; }
        public string Supplier_ID { get; set; }
        public string POID { get; set; }
        public string CreateDate { get; set; }
        public string CurrencyName { get; set; }
        public string ShippingStatus { get; set; }
        public string payment_terms { get; set; }
        public string shipping_terms { get; set; }
        public string POStatus { get; set; }
        public List<PurchaseOrderItems> PurchaseOrderItems { get; set; }
    }
    public class PurchaseOrderItems
    {
        public string SKU { get; set; }
        public string Product_ID { get; set; }
        public string QtyOrdered { get; set; }
        public string QtyOutstanding { get; set; }
        public string BuyPriceEx { get; set; }
        public string DirectCosts { get; set; }
        public string SupplierBuyPrice { get; set; }

    }
```

I fill the purchase order class using the following linq

```
        List<PurchaseOrder> _orderDetailed = items.Select(po => new PurchaseOrder()
        {
            WHID = (string)po.Element("WHID").ElementValueNull(),
            Supplier_ID = (string)po.Element("Supplier_ID").ElementValueNull(),
            POID = (string)po.Element("POID").ElementValueNull(),
            CreateDate = (string)po.Element("CreateDate").ElementValueNull(),
            CurrencyName = (string)po.Element("CurrencyName").ElementValueNull(),
            payment_terms = (string)po.Element("payment_terms").ElementValueNull(),
            shipping_terms = (string)po.Element("shipping_terms").ElementValueNull(),
            POStatus = (string)po.Element("POStatus").ElementValueNull(),
            PurchaseOrderItems = po.Descendants("PurchaseOrderItem").Select(i => new PurchaseOrderItems()
            {
                SKU = (string)i.Element("SKU").ElementValueNull(),
                Product_ID = (string)i.Element("Product_ID").ElementValueNull(),
                QtyOrdered = (string)i.Element("QtyOrdered").ElementValueNull()
            }).ToList()

        }).ToList();
```

The problem come when I pass this to a reflection function that write the object to csv. it only writes the PurchaseOrder fields to the file.  I have no idea how to access the PurchaseOrderItems fields so I can write them to the file.

I need to achieve the following using the above xml structure.

```
WHID Supplier_ID POID SKU    Product_ID QtyOrdered
2    00          6    Shoe30 124064     6
```

I have cut down the fields above just to keep it easy to read.  but the goal is to have all the line items and the purchase order header details on the one line.

```
public void WriteCSV<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string path)
{
    Type itemType = typeof(T);
    var props = itemType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                        .OrderBy(p => p.Name);

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(string.Join(fieldDelimiter, props.Select(p => p.Name)));

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(fieldDelimiter, props.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null))));
        }
    }
}
```

I know I am missing how object work here so looking for some direction.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use some csv library?

Comment: You will need to test the types of the properties and handle the `List` properties specially using`GetGenericArguments` and expanding it out - doing a type of flatten (or expand). You could also preprocess with LINQ and then use your existing `WriteCSV`.

Comment: Did you mean to have multiple line items spread horizontally on a single line, or to duplicate the header items and have one line per item? Perhaps your example should show multiple items?

Comment: @NetMage.  Appologies for it not being clear enough.  There should be a line for each item within the purchase order.  so if there are 3 line items then 3 lines should be written to file.  Each line needs to include the PO header details.  SO..   each row 1 header details ... line item 1 details row 2 header details ... line item 2 details etc etc

Comment: Please see my answer :)

Comment: @NetMage.... used it successfully and gave you the props.  Thanks heaps!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of handling it in `WriteCSV`, you could pre-process the data to flatten (denormalize) it and then pass it to your existing `WriteCSV`:

```
var flatten = l.SelectMany(po => po.PurchaseOrderItems.Select(pi => new {
    po.WHID,
    po.Supplier_ID,
    po.POID,
    pi.SKU,
    pi.Product_ID,
    pi.QtyOrdered,
}));

WriteCSV(flatten);
```

Comment: Close, but _"the goal is to have all the line items and the purchase order header details on the one line"_.

Comment: This writes a line per item. I read it as that the OP wants all items belonging to the same order on the same line, one after another.

Comment: @CodeCaster After I re-formatted the example in the OP, that is not what it seems to show...

Comment: What does this print for one order with two items?

Comment: @CodeCaster Two lines, with the PO Header duplicated and the individual items on each line, as per the sample in the original question.

Comment: That is not, quoting the OP, _"all the line items and the purchase order header details on the one line"_. Their example contains one item, it's a bad example to express their desired format. I interpret it as if they then wish to have the `SKU    Product_ID QtyOrdered` headings and data repeated horizontally.

Comment: @CodeCaster True, but the example (admittedly insufficient) did not show that (based on the headers). I put a comment on the OP asking for clarification...

Comment: So just wanted to confirm @NetMage got it correct.  I was able to run the following to flatten the Object and write the results to file.  I tried selectMany before but dont understand it at all so could never get this...